# How to preprocess a pandas dataset for TensorFlow

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tensorflow

I'm trying to do an experiment with using svg data on the mnist images as an input into a fullyconnected Neural Network in Tensorflow

I've parsed the images and put them into a csv file with each row a different image, the first column is the classifier (0-9) and the remaining columns are the coordinates (x1,y1,x2,y2 etc)

```
csv_file = '/content/mnist_training_0s_svg.csv'
    
max_features = 100 # the max number in reality is more like 70, will ultimately truncate
    
dataframe = pd.read_csv(csv_file, header=None, names = list(range(0,max_features))) 
    
print (dataframe.head())

    0    1    2   3   4   5    6   7    8   ...  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99

    0   0  180  196   0 -11  -5  -16 -14  -13  ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN

    1   0  152  203 -46 -18 -56 -153 -11 -153  ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN

    2   0  106  128 -21 -30 -21  -62   0  -54  ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN

    3   0  180   90  25 -25  60  -94  60 -119  ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN

    4   0  115  178 -20 -29 -20  -92   1 -109  ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN

    [5 rows x 100 columns]
```

What I'm trying to do next is use pad_sequences to add zeros and truncate each "image" to 70 coordinates and then use keras preprocessing to normalize the data so that it can be effectively intput into the NN.

```
    def df_to_dataset(dataframe, shuffle=True, batch_size=32):
         dataframe = dataframe.copy()
         labels = dataframe.pop(0) # 
         ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(dataframe)), labels))
         ds = pad_sequences(ds.as_numpy_iterator(), #TypeError: from_tensor_slices() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
         padding='post',truncating='post',maxlen=70)
         if shuffle:
         ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=len(dataframe))
         ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
         ds = ds.prefetch(batch_size)
         return ds

    train_ds = df_to_dataset(dataframe, batch_size = 5)
```

The details of the above is pretty arbitrary. I've tried many variations of the above only to get a variety of TypeErrors. I've gone through the pandas dataframe documentation and the pad_sequences documentation, but I feel I'm missing something more basic, namely, in layperson's terms: how do I pull out a row of this dataframe (minus the classifier) to pad and how do I pull out a column (minus the labels) to normalize?

Comment: from_tensor_slices takes one argument, but you're also passing labels. Try it again with passing only the dataframe.

Comment: @RJAdriaansen  thanks.  I was able to get past that error with that.  I'm still working on the rest, it seems like loc and iloc may be of some help.

Comment: @RJAdriaansen an extra set of parenthesis solved *that* problem without having to eliminate the labels.